# dns management. how to predict required # of queries per month?

Tags: domain-name-system

How cam I predict required # of queries per month?

One of these services says 5 million request per month, how many times would a site visitor request?  there are local caches so not sure how to get a rough idea?

Also, these services that are 20-30/year like easydns etc., how many domains do these packages  let you manage?

Comment: Related http://serverfault.com/questions/268223/how-many-sites-can-be-served-with-50-000-dns-queries?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's tricky... if you want to make sure you don't exceed your limits, one request per page-view should be a good metric.  However, the more you know about your visitor patterns and the length of their stays, combined with your TTL preferences, the better you can refine that figure.

Comment: Agreed.  If downtime (being cut off) is going to cause you grief, assume the worst case of 1 per page view and go from there.  You may also want to take into account DNS queries for mail (worst case, 1 per message as well).

Comment: womble why one request per page? If my browser has resolved the ip of a site then if I wade through many pages, will it try to resolve again in the same session (of 1 hour, for example)?

Comment: @AgA: Hence "If you want to make sure you don't exceed your limits" -- one DNS lookup per page view is the *worst case* estimate.  At the risk of *completely* duplicating my answer, if you know the average number of pages that each user visits (within the period of your TTL) then you can refine that estimate to something better.

Answer (score -1):

Largely this is irrelevant.  DNS uses virtually no data transfer, and commonly people have the cache time for records set to say, 24 or 48 hours, meaning one given ISP's caching nameservers will do only a few lookups every two days for all their customer traffic.

Comment: It's not irrelevant if your DNS provider limits you a certain number of DNS queries per month and turns off your DNS resolution if you exceed that limit.

Comment: JRD do you have any references? Also all DNS service providers give a limit in each plan. A free plan my limit maximum 300,000 qr/month. I'm sure those many clients are able to reach this limit else who'll buy their plans?